# Probability is not adding up correctly

Tags: probability

Suppose that most morning you set your alarm for 8am so that
you can catch the 8:30am bus to school which usually arrives just in time for your class at 9am.
Unfortunately, sometimes you forget to set your alarm which might make you miss your bus and
this increases the probability that you are late for class. Even if you catch the 8:30am bus, there’s
a chance you’ll be late for class. To help analyze the situation we introduce some random variables.

Let A = 1 if you remember to set your alarm and A = 0 otherwise.

Let B = 1 if you catch the
8:30am bus and B = 0 otherwise.

Let L = 1 if you are late for class and L = 0 otherwise.

Suppose
that

$P(A = 1)$ = 3/4,

$ P(B = 1|A = 1)$ = 4/5,

$P(B = 1|A = 0) $= 2/5,

$P(L = 1|B = 1)$ = 1/4,

and
$P(L = 1|B = 0)$ = 2/3.

What’s the values of:

$P(B = 1)$ , $P(L = 0)$ ?

Since B is dependent on A, I calculated that:

$P(B = 1)$ = $P(B=1|A=0)$ + $P(B=1|A=1)$

However, this gives me a final answer of 1.2 which is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: It's from the same problem but different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compute the probabilities of $B$ based on the conditional probabilities with respect to $A$, you need to take into account the actual probabilities that $A$ takes on.  You should actually have

$$
P(B = 1) \;\; =\;\; P(B=1 | A=0) P(A=0) + P(B=1| A=1) P(A=1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $P(L = 0)$.

$P(B = 0) = 1 - P(B = 1) =1 - P(B=1 | A=0) P(A=0) + P(B=1| A=1) P(A=1)$

$P(L = 1) = P(L = 1|B = 1)P(B = 1) + P(L = 1|B = 0)P(B = 0)$

$P(L = 1) = P(L = 1|B = 1)[P(B=1 | A=0) P(A=0) + P(B=1| A=1) P(A=1)]
+ P(L = 1|B = 0)[1 - P(B=1 | A=0) P(A=0) + P(B=1| A=1) P(A=1)]$

$P(L = 0) = 1 - P(L = 1)$